# How to set PATH environment variable?

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to `shutdown` my PC using the command prompt in Windows 7. But it says that the command `shutdown` doesn't exist.

Actually, I accidentally deleted the `path` variable in the environment variables and I suppose because of that, the command isn't found. How can I set the `path` variable to enable shutdown via command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Select Computer from the Start menu
2. Choose System Properties from the context menu
3. Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
4. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
5. In the Edit windows, modify PATH
6. use `;` (semicolon) for separating path entry texts

As you want shutdown.exe you want to have `%SystemRoot%\System32` in your path.

If you want to restore the path variable to the default then here is the entire string:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```