# Pip and distribute not working on Python 3.3

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to Python and I am trying to install it on Windows. I am starting to use it because I have to set-up a watch service for a Windows folder, and then update a database when there are changes in that folder. Searching online has led me to "Watchdog".

I am trying to install *csvkit* and *watchdog*, but I have had no success; `pip` and `easy_install` are both not doing anything.

Running Python 3.3.0 x86.
Windows 7 Professional
Installed [pip](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) and [distribute](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute) using msi.

When running Python command shell:

```
Input:
pip install watchdog

Output:
File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install watchdog
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Normal command prompt:

```
Input:
python pip install watchdog  

Output:
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

---

The solution below, as mentioned by Breakthrough, is correct:

```
Input:
pip install watchdog
```

But I received the error output because I was missing my `Scripts` folder in the Environmental Variables.

```
Output:
'pip' is not recognized ans an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Adding `C:\Python\Scripts` solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the syntax from [the official `pip` website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/), try `pip install [module]` from a normal command prompt (some modules require an elevated, administrative command prompt instead), instead of invoking it from a Python shell.  You can view the latest [`pip` usage document here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install).

If for some reason you cannot invoke `pip`, ensure that it can be found somewhere in your `PATH` environment variable (see the question [How to set PATH environment variable?](https://superuser.com/questions/562169/how-to-set-path-environment-variable) for further details).

---

By calling `python pip install watchdog`, you are attempting to invoke the file called `pip` from the current directory, as a Python script, passing it the remaining parameters as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. `'pip' is not recognized ans an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` is the result, I checked out my path variable and I was missing the `Scripts` folder. Thanks again!

Comment: @John not a problem, glad everything worked out.  I added a small note to the answer in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: Perfect! The path variables need to include the path to Python and the Python script folder. (eg. `C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts`)

Answer (score 0):

Clarify for newbies: in *cmd* navigate to C:\Python33\Scripts\ (print that: cd C:\Python33\Scripts)  and only than write `pip install [module]`

(note: i assume you have Python 3.3, if you have Python 2.7 then navigate to C:\Python27\Scripts)